# Taking numbers from a text file and add them together

Tags: scripting, perl

I have text file with hundreds of lines like below. I am trying to find a way to pull the number of records and add them together. Then I want to put the answer in a separate file This is my first script I have ever tried to write.

```
Record 4957 of message 1:
Record 3411 of message 1:
Record 2529 of message 1:
```

Answer (score 2):

Perl one-liner:

```
perl -ne '$c += $_ for m/(\d+)(?!=:)/g; }{ print $c' in.txt > out.txt
```

Perl script form:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $infile = 'in.txt';
my $outfile = 'out.txt';

open my $fh, '<', $infile
  or die $!;

my $count = 0;

while (my $line = <$fh>){
    my @line_count = $line =~ m/(\d+)(?!=:)/g;
    $count += $_ for @line_count;
}

close $fh or die $!;

open my $wfh, '>', $outfile
  or die $!;

print $wfh $count;

close $wfh or die $!;
```

Brief explanation: Collect all instances of one or more consecutive integers per line, as long as they aren't followed by an attached `:`. Then simply update a variable by adding those new values to it.

Comment: I'd golf your one-liner using the autosplit switch: `perl -anE '$c += $F[1] }{ say $c'`

Comment: Nice :) I always forget about the -a switch. I'll update when I'm not on my phone.

Comment: Fwiw, I did it the way I did because originally the OP had all the data on a single line.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry but I had to work out the obligatory awk answer.

```
awk '{sum+=$2}END{print "There are "sum" records."}' in.txt
```

Ninja edit do ensure that only lines with "Record" were summed.

```
awk '$1=="Record"{sum+=$2}END{print "There are "sum" records."}' in.txt
```

Comment: `grep -Eo '[0-9]{2,}' temp2.txt > temp3.txt`;

`awk '{ sum += $1 } END { print sum }' temp3.txt > BufWeekly`;

Comment: I originally tried this but I get an error for syntax every time

Comment: I tried your awk command too and I am getting the syntax error. I am doing something incorrect???

Comment: if you post the output of the one liner I'd be happy to take a look.